# Configuracion Equivalente MySQL en Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: mysql, windows, ubuntu

[image: Configuración Windows]

Buenas tardes.

Disculpen mi ignorancia en MySQL. En Windows salen 3 tipos de configuraciones (Ver Imagen): Desarrollo, Server y Dedicado. Como puedo reflejar esas mismas configuraciones en una ambiente linux, para mi caso ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Development Computer | La instalación equivalente en ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqld-dev
```

Server Computer | La instalación equivalente en ubuntu (es la mas común)

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Para Dedicate Computer necesitas editar archivos es algo mas complejo no encontré una instalacion como tal

Esta tabla indica los tipos de instalación para rpm Red hat, Centos y similares

[Tabla de instalación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/linux-installation-rpm.html)

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha resultado útil tu respuesta.